# Programmatically setting a Xtend class as super class of a Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, xtend

I am currently working on an Eclipse plugin. I want to set programmatically a Xtend class as super class of a Java class.
If both classes were Java classes I would do that with the JDT API. The problem is that I cannot access the Xtend classes through the Java AST or the Java Model.

This is what I tried to access the Xtend classes:

- using an `ASTParser`
- using `IJavaProject.findType()`

Is there a way to set a Xtend class as super class?
Is there a way to set a superclass with a string (package + class name), without the reference to the `IType` or `TypeDeclaration`?

**EDIT:** Both the Java class and the Xtend class already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the qualified name of the super class, you shouldn't need to access it via AST or Java Model, just the name is enough.

When you speak of setting a super class of a Java class, it's not clear if that class (a) is being created from scratch or (b) exists and is being modified. Still both scenarios can be performed using the public AST *(in case of (a) just create the AST and serialize it using, e.g., an `ASTFlattener`; in case of (b) you should use `ASTRewrite`)*.

Either way, the API you want to use is `TypeDeclaration.setSuperclassType(Type)`, where the argument is probably a `SimpleType` constructed from a `QualifiedName`:

```
void setSuperClass(TypeDeclaration typeDecl, String qualifiedName) {
    AST ast = typeDecl.getAST();
    Name name = ast.newName(qualifiedName);
    Type type = ast.newSimpleType(name);
    typeDecl.setSuperclassType(type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for. The classes already exist. I never used `ASTRewrite` before, can you tell me how it works?

Comment: Given we already spoke about the tutorial slides "How To Train the JDT Dragon", just skip to slide #46 for an intro. Additionally, much can be learned from browsing the implementation of JDT/UI, where all the quick fixes/assists & refactorings are implemented using ast rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I tried it with all your tips and other examples, but I am struggling to get the changes visible in the Java classes. I wrote a question here, because I ran out of ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279095/eclipse-ast-not-changing-class-files-when-changing-typedeclaration