# Eclipse AST not changing class files when changing TypeDeclaration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-pde

**I am trying to edit several Java classes with the Java AST. But my changes wont show in the Java class files.**

What specifically do I want to do? I want to take an `IPackageFragment` and visit all the `ICompilationUnit`s. For every declared class I want to set the super class to a specific class (using the qualified name of the super class, [because it is an Xtend class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189523/programmatically-setting-a-xtend-class-as-super-class-of-a-java-class)). I also tried applying the edits via the `Document` class.

**For example:** A class `main.model.someClass` should inherit from `wrappers.main.model.someClassWrapper`

I am relatively new to the JDT API, so I cannot find the reason why the class files are not changed. I already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317911/eclipse-ast-not-changing-files-which-are-not-opened-in-eclipse), but it did not help me. I tried to stay as close as possible to the examples from [How To Train the JDT Dragon](http://www.eclipsecon.org/2012/sites/eclipsecon.org.2012/files/How%20To%20Train%20the%20JDT%20Dragon%20combined.pdf) other tips/examples I got from Stackoverflow. But it will not work.

**This is how I do it:**

```
private void editTypesIn(IPackageFragment myPackage) throws JavaModelException {
    for (ICompilationUnit unit : myPackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
        TypeVisitor visitor = new TypeVisitor(myPackage.getElementName(), unit);
        unit.becomeWorkingCopy(new NullProgressMonitor());
        CompilationUnit parse = parse(unit);
        parse.recordModifications();
        parse.accept(visitor);
    }
}

private static CompilationUnit parse(ICompilationUnit unit) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    parser.setSource(unit);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    return (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); // parse
}
```

**And this is the visitor class:**

```
public class TypeVisitor extends ASTVisitor {
    private final String currentPackage;
    private final ICompilationUnit compilationUnit;

    public TypeVisitor(String currentPackage, ICompilationUnit compilationUnit) {
        this.currentPackage = currentPackage;
        this.compilationUnit = compilationUnit;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
        if (!node.isInterface()) { // is class
            setSuperClass(node, "wrappers." + currentPackage + "." + node.getName().toString() + "Wrapper");
        }
        return super.visit(node);
    }

    public void setSuperClass(TypeDeclaration declaration, String qualifiedName) {
        try {
            // create ast and rewrite:
            AST ast = declaration.getAST();
            ASTRewrite astRewrite = ASTRewrite.create(ast);
            // set super:
            Name name = ast.newName(qualifiedName);
            Type type = ast.newSimpleType(name);
            declaration.setSuperclassType(type);
            // apply changes
            TextEdit edits = astRewrite.rewriteAST();
            compilationUnit.applyTextEdit(edits, new NullProgressMonitor());
            compilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy(true, new NullProgressMonitor());
        } catch (JavaModelException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedTreeException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your edits will be empty, right?

By calling `CompilationUnit.recordModifications()` you tell the AST to internally create an `ASTRewrite` into which modifications will be recorded.

By `ASTRewrite.create(..)` you are creating a *second* `ASTRewrite` which knows nothing of the modifications being recorded.

The only API for consuming the recorded modifications is `CompilationUnit.rewrite(IDocument,Map)` (see references to field `AST.rewriter`).

If you need to use your own `ASTRewrite` apply the "Descriptive approach", using, e.g., `ASTRewrite.set(..)`.